# How to remove type in XML while generating?

Tags: c#, xml, json, ssis

I have 1000 records in text file. My requirement is to insert data into SQL Server. For that, if I can convert to XML or push to script component also fine.

Source Text file consists in this format...

```
[{"ID":1,"Name":"test1","State":"AP"},{"ID":2,"Name":"test2","State":"KN"},{"ID":3,"Name":"test3","State":null}]
```

---

```
String json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\t1.txt");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
  var quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
  var jasonreader - JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJasonReader(stream,quotas);
  var xml = XDocument.Load(jsonreader);
  xmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();

  using (steamwriter fs = new streamwriter(@"C:\t.xml");
{
  fs.write(xml);
}
  console.writeLine(xml);
}
```

Output -

```
<root type="array"
  <item type="object">
     <ID type="number">1</ID>
     <Name type="string">test1</Name>
     <State type="string">AP</State>
  </item>
<item type="object">
<root type="array"
  <item type="object">
     <ID type="number">2</ID>
     <Name type="string">test2</Name>
     <State type="string">KN</State>
  </item>
<item type="object">
<root type="array"
  <item type="object">
     <ID type="number">3</ID>
     <Name type="string">test3</Name>
     <State type="string"></State>
  </item>
</root>
```

When am using SSIS XML Source task, am getting columns...

External Columns:

```
type
text
item_id
```

Output Columns:

```
type
text
item_id
```

Ideally, I should get ID, Name, and State columns. What is the issue? How can I get rid of type in XML?

Answer (score 1):

How about using Linq? (using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json))

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filename));
XElement root = new XElement("root");

foreach(JObject jObj in jArr )
{
    root.Add(new XElement("item", jObj.Properties()
                                      .Select(p => new XElement(p.Name, 
                                                                p.Value.ToString()))
                                      .ToArray()));
}

var xml = root.ToString();
```

or using more linq

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filename));
XElement root = new XElement("root");
root.Add( jArr.Cast<JObject>()
              .Select(jObj => new XElement("item", jObj.Properties()
                                                       .Select(p => new XElement(p.Name, 
                                                                                 p.Value.ToString()))
                                                       .ToArray())));

var xml = root.ToString();
```

Comment: As I said, am new to coding, could you please tell me where should I add your code in my code?

Comment: @DineshKal Remove all your code, replace `filename` with your real filename and `xml` is your final xml string.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. What is jobject? I think i have to download newtonking assemblies, which is not possible because 3rd party stuff is not allowed. Please advise...

Comment: Finally, I'm am able to produce xml file. But I am facing challenge to insert data into MS SQL DB. I'm not getting any error as well...:-(. Can someone help me out...I'm using script task to generate file and data flow task consist of source=XML Source and destination as OLE db. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6f0e2d1-45da-4959-94e5-e92fccdbcb52/need-help-on-json-file-to-xml-or-scirpt-component?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: @DineshKal, how you have removed type from that?

Comment: @Termininja  I rolled it back. don't edit the answer, if you are not doing any useful.

Comment: No problem, but your code is bad formatted so in this case my action was more than useful.